# How to find the parent network device for a PPPoE device

Tags: linux, process, ethernet, ppp, pppd

For a POINTOPOINT [PPPoE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol_over_Ethernet) `ppp0` device in Linux, how to get the underlying ethernet device in a reliable way?

I've looked in the output of `ip -d link` and in the `/sys/class/net/ppp0` directory, but neither mention the parent device, nor the PID of the pppd process.

If only one pppd runs on the system, then there is a "workaround":

```
$ cat /proc/net/pppoe
Id       Address           Device
0000516D dc:99:16:c4:58:35 wan.25
```

In this case, `wan.25` is the wanted info.

But that "Id" `0000516D` I have not seen other places linking it to the PPP device. So how would I differentiate between several PPPoE interfaces?

Answer (score 2):

On re-reading the [`pppd` manpage](https://ppp.samba.org/pppd.html) I saw that `/var/run/pppd2.tdb` is not for MultiLink only, but stores information in [TDB format](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/TDB).

The man-page does not detail how to interrogate this file, but I was able to figure it out:

Note: You'll need the optional [tdb-tools package](https://packages.debian.org/stable/tdb-tools) or equivalent from your distribution.

```sh
$ D="inet"   # The name of your PPPoE interface
$ T="/copy/of/pppd2.tdb"

$ tdbdump $T -k IFNAME=$D
pppd34491
$ cID="pppd34491"
```

That ID 'pppd34491' can then be used to lookup other connection info in this Database copy for that connection. The information is stored as semicolon-separated  key=value pairs, so for viewing you can pass that through e.g. `awk`:

```sh
$ tdbdump $T -k $cID | awk 'BEGIN{RS=";";FS="="}{print $1" "$2}' |column -t
CALL_FILE   Provider
DEVICE      wan.25
MACREMOTE   So:me:ma:cc:cc:cc
IFNAME      inet
IPLOCAL     MyIPV4
IPREMOTE    PeerIPv4
```

(some less interesting stuff cut out)